# bytearray in python using hexadecimal values

Tags: python, arrays, hex, byte

I am wanting to use hexadecimal values when working with bytes. However I'm not quite sure on how this is done. For instance:

```
>>> bytearray([0x10,0x20,0x30])
bytearray(b'\x10 0')
```

Why are `0x20` and `0x30` ignored?

Answer (score 1):

`0x20` and `0x30` are not ignored: a `bytearray` is formatted like ASCII-characters and `0x20` happens to be the ASCII-code for a space (), the same for `0x30` which maps to a zero (`0`).

This is simply a compact way to represent a binary array. You can read all values and their corresponding characters in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart).

In case the character is **not** printable, it is formatted as `\x??` with `??` the hexadecimal code.

Answer (score 1):

They are not ignored. `0x20` is the ASCII codepoint for a space, `0x30` is the digit `0`. Both are there in the output, following the `\x10` byte.

What you are seeing is the *representation* of the bytes value, which tries to be as readable as possible. It does so by displaying any byte in the printable ASCII range as that ASCII character. Anything not so representable is shown either as a `\xhh` escape sequence or a shorter two character `\?` escape (such as `\n` for a newline or `\t` for a tab character).

Note that Python produces an integer value for each `0xhh` hex notation; it's nothing more than alternative syntax to produce the same integer value. You could have used decimal notation or octal notation too, and the result would have been the same; you are putting *integer values* into a `list` object, from which you then create a `bytearray` object. The original hex notation is *not preserved* in this process:

```
>>> [0x10, 0x20, 0x30]
[16, 32, 48]
>>> bytearray([16, 32, 48])
bytearray(b'\x10 0')
>>> [0o20, 0o40, 0o60]
[16, 32, 48]
>>> bytearray([0o20, 0o40, 0o60])
bytearray(b'\x10 0')
```

The actual values in the `bytearray` are still integers anyway; if you index into the object you get the individual byte values:

```
>>> ba = bytearray([0x10, 0x20, 0x30])
>>> ba
bytearray(b'\x10 0')
>>> ba[1]  # 0x20, the space
32
>>> ba[2]  # 0x30, the 0 digit
48
```

Comment: Could you also possibly show me how to treat a bytearray as a stream, such as x = bytearray([0x10,0x20,0x30]) and x.read(1) = 16, x.read(1) = 32

Comment: @ritch: use `io.BytesIO()` instead if you need a byte stream.

Comment: @ritch: so `x = io.BytesIO(bytes([0x10, 0x20, 0x30]))`, then `x.read(1)`, etc.

Comment: I have been doing that - I do `b = x.read(1)` and then do `print b` i get blank. How do I get it store numeric value not ascii representation?